# Should autovacuum be set to on?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a PostgreSQL 9.1 db running on Amazon EC2/EBS. The database has started to slow down. We have one table with 1m records that appears to be slowing everything down. When looking at the Postgres config we noticed the autovacuum setting was commented out.

What's the right way to approach this problem? Should autovacuum be set to on? Should we have some cron that autovacuums on a set interval? How does one know if a database should be vacuumed?

Comment: The very short answer is: Yes, basically always - even for read-only databases. Turning autovacuum off is an extremely advanced option these days; instead most people should be tuning autovacuum cost parameters, etc.

Comment: Are you sure `autovacuum` option in your `postgresql.conf` is **commented out**? It means that **autovacuum is enabled**, as it is [enabled by default](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-autovacuum.html). It has to be uncommented and set to `off` to be disabled. Connect to your database and run `show autovacuum;` to check this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Turn autovacuum on
2. Run, from `psql`: VACUUM VERBOSE ANALYZE the table. And read the output.

Generally speaking - you want autovacuum on, and occasionally you might want to run VACUUM manually, if you'll notice anything wrong.

Comment: re: #2, what will that do? How can I first analyze if I need a vacuum and then actually run the vacuum? Thanks

Comment: Also, we had a table w 1m records, all the rows were mistakenly deleted, so we restored the rows from a backup. Then performance really got horrible. Does this sound like a job for vacuum? Thanks

Comment: Definitely. delete + insert means table is heavily bloated. And all of its indexes, most likely, too.

Comment: #2 is so you'll see what is the current state of database. And "ANALYZE" has nothing to do with checking whether you should VACUUM. Analyze is to update system statistics about the table.

Comment: I just ran psql: VACUUM VERBOSE ANALYZE locally and got pages out output. What do you look at to know if anything was done, performances were gained? Thanks

Comment: Run some queries. And I suggested to run "VACUUM VERBOSE ANALYZE the table" - i.e. with table name. You'd get less output.

Answer (score 6):

The frequency which autovacuum should run is based on how often your database modifies records.  If your database is constantly doing deletes and updates then you're going to want to run autovacuum often.  If your database/schema is simply adding to the database and rarely doing an update or delete, then you won't need to run it very often.

Autovacuum is just for reclaiming memory/storage space which the database is no longer using.

Comment: When I do a prod db backup, and restore locally a vacuum does nothing. Does a restored backup not reproduce the inefficiencies seen on a live master db?

Comment: No it does not.  When you do a db delete (or update I believe), postgresql will modify the table so that it can no longer access that old record however it doesn't actually delete anything from memory or the disk.  Doing an autovacuum will find all of these rows that now longer have tables associated with them and delete them from memory/disk.  When you do a database backup it will back up all the rows currently associated with the database's tables, not the rows who no longer have a table associated.  Therefor doing a restore will not restore these rows.